# Spring Boot: serving static content with war packagin

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I was trying to use auto configured serving static content in spring boot.
I read it is enough to put that content to `/static/` or `/resources/` and configure on `@Controller` in order to do it.

In my project it looks like it does not work at all.

I have compared it with `spring-boot-sample-web-ui` and the only thing I have different is packaging. There is `jar` and I have `war` packaging.

Could you please confirm me that in spring-boot in `war` packaging this auto configured static content serving does not work?

Comment: You don't need to configure anything. Just put a directory `/static` or `/template` in your classpath (i.e. in `src/main/resources` and the content will be served). Don't put a mapping on a controller for this URL.

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding I have not configured anything. I have just created simple class and annotated it with @Controller. I have not put any mappings also.

Comment: Judging from what you wrote you have a `@Controller` with a `@RequestMapping("/static")`. A class only with `@Controller` without `@RequestMapping` is pretty useless.

Comment: http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot I have done stuff similar to steps described in above link.

Comment: @fire did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

First create a folder named `static` in `src/main/resources`.

Now if you want something to be displayed by default you can add an index.html to that folder and you can display that as your landing page (Ex: `http://localhost:8080/my-app-name`)

Then, if you have other content you can create folders by type put those inside.

Ex:

```
images  -> src/main/resources/static/images
js  -> src/main/resources/static/js
```

If you put `login.js` file inside above `js` folder, you can access it now from the url `http://localhost:8080/my-app-name/js/login.js`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of the `main` method, you need to define a servletInitializer (this one is an alternative to creating a web.xml)

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class MyServletInitializerextends extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Edit: Don't forget to add it to the componentScan